# Could not access deployed SOAP services in Mule EE

Tags: soap, deployment, mule

I developed a SOAP service on custom port 8071. That worked fine in Studio environment. After deploying to Mule EE 3.4.1, I can't access the service on same port.

Can someone please advise what configuration changes are required in Mule/Tomcat config to enable new HTTP port?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mule/Tomcat"? Are you deploying to Mule EE Standalone or Tomcat?

Comment: App deployed to Mule EE Standalone, MMC running on Tomcat

Comment: Cool, is the app deployed successfully? Any error in the logs?

Comment: Yes, app is deployed green, no error in logs.

Comment: To what host do you bind the HTTP endpoint? `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` or...? If you `telnet localhost 8071` can you connect?

Comment: To the hostname. telnet is not running there

Comment: By telnet is not running here, do you mean that telnet fails to connect to localhost?

Comment: I mean it gives unknown service error

Comment: Oh wow, never seen that before.

Comment: sorry, telnet localhost gives "Connection refused"

Comment: Mule logs writes "[09-29 12:51:18] INFO  HttpConnector [1657100523@qtp-1884455763-6]: Registering listener: SupplierMaintUtils-svc on endpointUri: http://ssv2077:8071/Services/SMT/SupplierUtils" but URI/wsdl is not accessible from browser

Comment: Just tested that service is accessible locally but new port 8071 needs to added to network firewall to enable remote access.